# jQuery UI Dialog - How to open dialog from a link in iframe

Tags: jquery, user-interface, iframe, dialog

I want to open a dialog from a link i iframe,however I cannot make it pop-up a dialog
anybody knows the reason?

I have a iFrame in html
`<iframe src="Add_Reviewer.html" width="100%" name="test" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" height="100%"></iframe>`

My link in Add_Reviewer.html
`<a href="#" id="advance_add">Advance Add</a>`

My jQuery Code

```
var $advance_add = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<iframe src="Advance_Add.html" width="100%" name="test" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" height="100%">')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        bgiframe: true,
        width:650,
        minWidth: 650,
        height: 550,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        modal:true,
        title: 'Addvance Add',
        buttons : {

                    "Close" : function() {
                                  $(this).dialog("close");
                                          }
        }
    });

$("#advance_add").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();     
$advance_add.dialog('open');

});
```

Comment: Are you loading jQuery + jQuery UI within the iFrame or the parent file?

Answer (score 2):

I am using this code:

```
$("#advance_add").click(function() {
    $('<iframe src="Advance_Add.html" frameborder="0" />').dialog({
        modal: true,
        dialogClass: 'priceBox',
        title: 'Your title',        
        height: 400,
        width: 500,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false});
});
```